# How can I create an array including all matches of a regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function which is supposed to put all matches `regex` returns when executed against a string `str` into the array `res` and then return it:

```
function matchAll(str, regex) {
    var res = [];
    var m;

        while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
            res.push(m[0]);
        }

    return res;
}
```

It creates an infinite loop with the regex `/^\d\d*/i`. Why?

Comment: will it always be a "number space three characters" as a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `\d\s[A-Z0-9]{3,3}`

RegexPal (working solution): http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=96072